# Getting Resources$NotFoundException for layouts in nested folders

Tags: android, android-layout

I recently refactored my layout folders to include several sub folders. This helps me organize my layouts better. Even though Android doesn't natively support it, I added the new ressource folder in my build.gradle. Here is my current layouts structure.

Current res folder:

[image]

Current layouts folder:

[image]

In my build.gradle app. I added the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs += ['src\\main\\res\\layouts', 'src\\main\\res\\layouts\\king_panel', 'src\\main\\res\\layouts\\king_panel\\layout']
    }
}
```

I am getting this error saying that the resource id couldn't be found for the layout in king_panel folder.

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62 in
> :layout/activite_king_main: Binary XML file line #18 in
> :layout/king_panel_geoloc: Resource ID #0x7f0d00a0
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in
> :layout/king_panel_geoloc: Resource ID #0x7f0d00a0
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
> ID #0x7f0d00a0
> at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:236)
> at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2446)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1252)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1232)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1140)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
> at
> framework.affichage.desktop.IVue_Fragment.onCreateView(IVue_Fragment.java:89)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:386)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1147)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1147)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
> 2024-03-01 14:17:35.475 11778-11778 AndroidRuntime
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
> at
> vue.activite.VAct_King_Tiles_Horizontal.onCreate(VAct_King_Tiles_Horizontal.java:83)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8050)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8030)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3648)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3832)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2247)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7880)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)

I am on gradle

Comment: Android does not support nested resource directories like this very well. Since you are already using a prefix (`king_panel_`), it is unclear what you are gaining by adding this extra level of complexity. If you have too many resources in a single module, a more likely solution is to have multiple modules.

Comment: having a 100+ layout file in the same directory is getting hard to go through and manage

Comment: Then use multiple modules.

Comment: can you share an article about that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization